# Retaining responsive table inside container

Tags: html, css

Im having hard time with keeping (responsive) table inside container. Im using collapsable Javascript script for openening and closing table div. If there is large number of columns, table keeps spilling outside container, and i would like to keep the table and all contents inside. This is (important divs and containers) HTML script:

```css
body {
background: url(img/bg.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
color: #666;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}

#pagewrap {
padding: 5px;
width: 1800px;
margin: 20px auto;
}

#middle {
width: 1220px; 
float: left;
padding: 5px 15px;
margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.table{
display:table; 
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
border-bottom:2px solid #dddddd;
color:#8d8d8d;
margin:10px 0; 
}
.table-head{
 display: table-header-group; 
 }
 .table-head .column{ 
 background:#333333;
 color:#7d7d;
 border-right:1px solid #5d5d5d;
 border-bottom:none;
 vertical-align: middle;
 }
 .row{
 display:table-row;
 }
 .row .column:nth-child(1){ 
 border-left:1px solid #eeeeee;
 }
 .row:last-child .column{  
 border-bottom:none;
 }
 .column{
 display:table-cell; 
 padding:10px 20px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee;
 border-right:1px solid #eeeeee;
 }
```

```html
<body>     
<div id="pagewrap">
<section id="middle">

<a href="#collapse1" onclick="$('p').show();return false;" class="nav-toggle">+ See details</a>
<div id="collapse1" style="display:none">

<div class="table">
<div class="table-head">
<div class="column" data-label="">ID</div>
<div class="column" data-label="">Name</div>
<div class="column" data-label="">Surname</div>
                   more colums here...
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` to the container.

Comment: Fair enough, but can i make that table more responsive instead of scrollable content ?

Comment: @greedy when the content is too big for the container, you cannot do anything. You could display only overview in the table and the detail on row click. Other possibilities are paging, filtering, making a hierarchy (e.g. food-fruit-apple...)